# How to retrieve information using PDO method

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am building a login script using the PDO method. I would like to register some sessions from the user account. Every time I try to pull information from the database I get blank. I am new to PDO. Here is what I have so far:

```
try{
$conn = new PDO(...........);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
$conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE USER = ':user' AND pass = ':pass'";

$UpdateSql = $conn->prepare($sql);
$UpdateSql->bindValue(':user',$user,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$UpdateSql->bindValue(':pass',$pass,PDO::PARAM_STR);

$results = $UpdateSql->execute();

/*Here is where the error comes in
foreach($results as $row)
{
$_SESSION['account'] = $row['account'];
}
*/

/*I also tried this
foreach($UpdateSql as $row)
{
$_SESSION['account'] = $row['account'];
}
*/

}catch(PDOException $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

When I tried the first foreach() I received an error **Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\drug_center\dc_login.php on line 26** and the second foreach() gave me an empty result. Can someone please explain to me where I am making my mistake?

Comment: Use either `foreach($UpdateSql->fetchAll() as $row)` or `while($row = $UpdateSql->fetch())`. The return of `execute()` is just a boolean to indicate whether everything went OK or not. Also, strictly speaking you shouldn't quote your parameters (`':user'` should be `:user`).

Comment: @Wrikken when I do not quote my parameters I receive the following error **Warning: PDO::query() [pdo.query]: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':user AND pass = :pass' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\drug_center\dc_login.php on line 19

Fatal error: Call to a member function bindValue() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\drug_center\dc_login.php on line 21**

Comment: @Brian: Well. that's correct. I said you should do it in the `->prepare()` statement above. NOT a `->query()`. Those are 2 different things, very different.

Comment: @Wrikken please explain.......

Comment: The `prepare()` method prepares the sql statement which you can execute with `execute()` even multiple times with different variables.
With `query()` you just directly query the database.

Comment: Prepared statement get sent to the server before you even execute them, so it already knows the type of query it's going to perform, and just waits for the values of the known placeholders & an execute command. Queries are sent as raw strings & parsed & executed directly. The type of variables you are sending for the placeholders is determined  when you send those (string, integer, float, blob), and as the server know what placeholders are, there is therefor no need to quote them in the statement, there can be no syntax errors. That's about what fits in a comment here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll be needing the `$UpdateSql->fetchAll()` method. This will give you a result set which can be traversed.

Secondly you'll be specyfing the parameters trough bindValue, so you don't need the ' around the values.

```
$table = (in_array($table, array('table1','table2')) ? $table : false;
//make sure you put some input-validation on the $table variabel!!

if($table){
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE user = :user AND pass = :pass";
  //lose the ' around the :pass


  $UpdateSql = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $UpdateSql->bindValue(':user',$user,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $UpdateSql->bindValue(':pass',$pass,PDO::PARAM_STR);

  $UpdateSql->execute();
  foreach($UpdateSql->fetchAll() AS $row){
    // do some magic
  }
}else{
  throw new Exception("Error: table not allowed", 1);
}
```

Comment: woot .. saved  me a line .. reduced code = good.

Comment: I am using this and it is giving me an empty result.

Comment: @Bryan make sure that `$table`, `$user` and `$pass` have a value.

Comment: @stUrb Yes they all have values. I already ensure that.

Answer (score 0):

Execute is to run a stored procedure on a SQL Server, you can

```
$results = $UpdateSql->fetchAll($sql);
foreach ($results as $row) 
     //stuff
}
```

Comment: Eeuh, you need to run the `->execute()` other wise the prepared statement won't be executed.

Answer (score 0):

The function prepare() returns an object of [PDOStatement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) class. As it says on the PHP manual, [PDOStatement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php)::[execute()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) does not return results, it returns a boolean instead to indicate if the query was successful or not. You need to use the [fetch commands](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) the PDOStatement has.